# How to provide "_" as a part of table name format in ListDataBaseTables (NiFi)

Tags: java, apache-nifi

I would like to extract the list of tables which are in certain format using ListDatabaseTable nifi processor:-

**tables in db**

```
cus_1
emp_1
cus_2
emp_2
cus_3
emp_3
```

From above list of tables I would like to extract those tables which are of "_1" and "_3".

As per [documentation](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ListDatabaseTables/index.html) "_" has predefined meaning.

So How can I include "_" as a part of table name format ?? And Can we provide multiple conditions / table name formats??

Comment: I think it uses database `like` operation. Try to read the  manual for your database. For example mssql supports this: `%[_][13]`

Answer (score 0):

NiFi uses `java.sql.DatabaseMetaData` to access. The interface has a `getSearchStringEscape` to give the escape character. Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to available through the processor.

The usual escape is `\` character. You can check whether that works for the particular database you are using.

In your case, that doesn't seem to be enough since you are checking for `_[0-9]` and you can provide only a single table name pattern. Better option may be to retrieve all tables and then filter out using `RouteOnAttribute`.